# Can Eurozone countries issue their own bonds?

Tags: european-union

Can Eurozone countries issue their own bonds, or is this a delegated competency?

If not, how do such countries raise funds for big uncosted spending such as infrastructure projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issuing bond is indeed the competence of the individual states.

For example, you can buy 10 year bonds both from Italy and Germany, both of which are Eurozone countries:
https://www.investing.com/rates-bonds/de-10y-vs-it-10y